# HashMap performance Java 9 25% less than Java 8?

Tags: performance-testing, java-9, jmh

> Note: This is **not** about a performance issue. I only observe a difference in performance I cannot explain / understand.

While benchmarking some newly developed code, targeted for Java 9 I discovered something weird. A (very) simple benchmark of `HashMap` with 5 keys reveals that Java 9 is much slower than Java 8. Can this be explained or is my (benchmark) code just plain wrong?

Code:

```
@Fork(
    jvmArgsAppend = {"-Xmx512M", "-disablesystemassertions"}
)
public class JsonBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class Data {

        final static Locale RUSSIAN = new Locale("ru");
        final static Locale DUTCH = new Locale("nl");

        final Map<Locale, String> hashmap = new HashMap<>();

        public Data() {
            hashmap.put(Locale.ENGLISH, "Flat flashing adjustable for flat angled roof with swivel");
            hashmap.put(Locale.FRENCH, "Solin pour toit plat inclinée");
            hashmap.put(Locale.GERMAN, "Flachdachkragen Flach Schrägdach");
            hashmap.put(DUTCH, "Plakplaat vlak/hellend dak inclusief glijschaal");
            hashmap.put(RUSSIAN, "Проход через плоскую кровлю регулир. для накл. кровли");
        }

    }

    @Benchmark
    public int bmHashMap(JsonBenchmark.Data data) {
        final Map<Locale, String> m = data.hashmap;
        int sum = 0;
        sum += m.get(Data.RUSSIAN).length();
        sum += m.get(Locale.FRENCH).length();
        sum += m.get(Data.DUTCH).length();
        sum += m.get(Locale.ENGLISH).length();
        sum += m.get(Locale.GERMAN).length();
        return sum;
    }    

}
```

Results:

- Java 8_151: JsonBenchmark.bmHashMap    thrpt   40  47948546.439 ± 560763.711  ops/s
- Java 9_181: JsonBenchmark.bmHashMap    thrpt   40  34962904.479 ± 276045.691  ops/s (**-/- 27%**!)

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the answers and great comments.

1. Suggestion by @Holger. My first reaction was: That must be the explanation. However, if I only benchmark the `String#length()` function, there is no significant difference in performance. And, when I only benchmark the `HashMap#get()` methods (as suggested by @Eugene) there is still a difference of about 10 - 12 %.
2. Suggestion by @Eugene. I changed the parameters (more warmup iterations, more memory), but I am not able to reproduce your outcome. I increased the heap to 4G however. But this cannot explain the difference, is not it?
3. Suggestion by @Alan Bateman. Yes, this improves the performance! However, still a difference of around 20%.

Answer (score 11):

You are testing more than just `HashMap`. You are not only calling `HashMap.get`, you are implicitly calling `Locale.hashCode` and `Locale.equals`. Further, you are calling `String.length`.

Now, all four could have changed their performance characteristics, so you would need far more tests to reason about which method(s) exhibit(s) different performance.

But the hottest candidate is `String.length`. In Java 9, the `String` class does not use a `char[]` array anymore, but a `byte[]` array, to encode Latin 1 strings using only one byte per character, dramatically reducing the memory footprint of typical applications. This, however, implies that the length is not always identical to the array length anymore. So the complexity of this operation has changed.

But keep in mind that your result is about 77 ns difference *in a microbenchmark*. This is not enough to estimate the impact on a real application…

Comment: Though this could be a little much of an ask and I wouldn't mind you denying this altogether. But (being a novice in jmh) if possible, could you state a complexity comparison of the `.length` in both the versions. Would be great to see that in the answer and statistical while understanding. Looked up [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~shade/8085796/notes.txt) to see if I could find out something, but most of it went over my head.

Comment: Good answer. Another thing to mention is -XX:-CompactStrings to see the performance different when not using compact strings.

Comment: @nullpointer: The old implementation was like `array.length`, the new implementation is like `arrays.length>>coder` wheres coder is either zero or one, depending on the string. The impact one a real application depends on how often `length()` is actually invoked and the ratio between latin1 strings and other strings. Some other string operations might be even faster for latin1 string (less bytes to shovel around), which may more than compensate.

Comment: @Holger I like how Aleksey (the same person working on this and `jol`) said that adding `coder` field would not make String class any bigger, the space for it was already there because of 8 bytes alignment.

Comment: @Eugene: and it’s still less fields than it had back then, when it had an `offset` and `length` field (before Java7, update6).

Comment: @Eugene Do you have a link/reference to this statement?

Comment: @rmuller I'll try to dig it out... it was from a JUG if i recall correctly.

Answer (score 6):

I had a hint this was about `jmh` set-up, more then it was about `HashMap`. As already noted you are measuring *a lot* more than simply `HashMap::get` here. But even so, I had doubts that java-9 would be that much slower, so I measured myself (latest jmh build from sources, java-8 and 9).

I haven't changed your code - just added way more heap (10GB) and way more warm-ups, thus reducing the "error" you see after `±`

Using java-8:

```
Benchmark            Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
SOExample.bmHashMap  avgt   25  22.059 ± 0.276  ns/op
```

Using java-9:

```
Benchmark            Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
SOExample.bmHashMap  avgt   25  23.954 ± 0.383  ns/op
```

The results are on-par pretty much without a noticeable difference (these are nano-seconds after all) as you see it. Also if you *really* want to test just `HashMap::get` than your methods could simply return the invocation of that, like this:

```
@Benchmark
@Fork(5)
public int bmHashMap(SOExample.Data data) {
    return data.hashmap.get(data.key); // where key is a random generated possible key
}
```